# how to get specific sub-category post only using wp_query

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-modal, categories

I have a modal category and in my modal category i have three sub-categories in it. Here is the structure of my modal category.

```
-Modal
  -Water Pumps
  -Water Heaters
  -Electrical
```

Here, i want to only get a post from my water pumps sub-category from my Modal category and to be displayed in my modal. Here is my code where it displays all that has a category name of modal, how can i restrict it to category name modal and sub-category of water pumps

```
<div id="myModal38" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
<?php $args1 = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'category_name' => 'modal',
                    'posts_per_page' => '1',
                );
    $modalPost = new WP_Query( $args1 );
    if( $modalPost->have_posts() ) : 
?>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <?php while ( $modalPost->have_posts() ) : $modalPost->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>       
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<!-- Modal -->
```

Comment: you can use 'tax_query' parameter of wp_query argument. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/150247/retrieve-posts-by-term-id-custom-query

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load the posts from the "Modal" and "Water Pumps" categories, you can use the following WP Query arguments:

```
$args1 = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'include_children' => false,
                'field' => 'name',
                'terms'    => array('Modal', 'Water Pumps')
            )
        )
    );
```

The include_children option is set to false, so that it won't load the rest of the Modal subcategories.
By following your example, the code loads the categories by name however it might be safer to use IDs instead and remove the `'field' => 'name'` option, so that the code would still work if you rename the categories.

Comment: hello sir thank you for your answer. Modal is a parent category of water pumps, and what i want is display the post of water pumps only that is being a child of modal category

Comment: Do you mean that if you have Post 1 assigned to "Water Pumps" and then Post 2 assigned to "Water Pumps" and "Modal", the query should show only Post 2?

Answer (score 1):

Query a specific child category from a specific parent category. It's provided as @Ben's answer doesn't work properly.

```
$args1 = array(
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'category_name' => 'Modal',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                'include_children' => false,
                                'field' => 'name',
                                'terms'    => array('Water Pumps')
                            ),
                        ),
         );

        $modalPost = new WP_Query( $args1 );
```